# Pass data through two activities using interface

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, interface

I have to pass a lot of data from 'Activity 1' to a 'Activity 2'. This data is condensed on a POJO with a lot of subclass on itself.

So, I figured I need to pass this data with an interface, this because I need use previous data to call a web service. But at the moment of reach the web service, the data is null.

Actually this is my code, but is not working:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ....
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.continue_button:
            continueToNewScreen();
            break;
    }
  }

  private void continueToNewScreen() {
    if (infoResult != null && infoResult.size() > 0) {
        eventsListener = new SecondActivity();
        eventsListener.callback(myObjectToSend);
        //send data to the next activity and start it.
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EventsListener {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          configurateView();
          manageEvent();
      }

    @Override
    public void callback(InfoEvent event) {
        Log.d("callback", "callback: ");
        //here the object is informed
        infoEvent = event;

    }

  private void manageEvent() {
    //call web service with the info from the last activity
    //here the object is null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) `putExtra()` method and [`Serializable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable) or [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) in order to send some data from one activity to another.
Actually in your case you must make your `myObjectToSend` class to implements `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and then pass it with help of `putExtra()` method.

In FirstActivity:

```
intent.putExtra("KEY", myObjectToSend);
```

which `KEY` can be a constant for getting this object in SecondActivity.

In SecondActivity `onCreate()` method:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        yourObjectToReceive = null;
    } else {
        yourObjectToReceive = (YourObjectToReceiveClass) extras.getSerializable("KEY");
    }
} else {
    yourObjectToReceive = (YourObjectToReceiveClass)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("KEY");
}
```